# Are query strings case sentitive?

Tags: apex

When I'm building out a URL under what circumstances  are query strings case sensitive? In Apex ? When I'm invoking JavaScript in a custom page to call an apex class? Or when I'm in JavaScript in general ? How about REST calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REST` parameters and `Page` parameters are indeed case sensitive. For example I would normally do the following to support case-insensitive parameters:

```
public String getIgnoreCase(String parameter)
{
    Map<String, String> parameters = RestContext.request.params;
    // alternatively ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters()
    for (String exactKey : parameters.keySet())
    {
        if (exactKey == parameter) // case insensitive
        {
            return parameters.get(exactKey);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Perhaps there is a more efficient case-insensitive hash table I am not aware of in Apex.